# LLVM and eclipse

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, llvm-clang

I'm trying to use Clang++ with Eclipse and I can't figuring out how to do it.

I'm on Eclipse Oxygen.2 (company constraint). I've installed CDT 9.4.3 with LLVM-Family Compiler Build Support 9.4.3 as well.

LLVM 8 is installed via their installer.

I'm trying to change the toolchain of a project, but LLVM was not listed. I've unchecked "Display compatible toolchains only" and picked up `LLVM with static compiler (Windows)`.

In the preferences, I've set up `LLVM Installation folder` to `C:\Program Files\LLVM\`

But eclipse says it is not detected.

What am I missing?

Comment: Have you added LLVM path as path in Environment Variables?

Comment: Yes it is, I can call clang++ from the console. `C:\Program Files\LLVM\bin` is in the PATH

Comment: I've changed to "LLVM with Clang (Windows) (Cygwin)" and even if Cygwin is not installed, I can now call clang++ from eclipse (compiling one file) but the include path is wrong. And I still have the eclipse error message about not detected

Comment: When compililng, why does clang use Visual studio's include?